# Subclassing NSTableHeaderCell / NSTableHeaderView to make transparent header

Tags: cocoa, nstableheaderview

for give me if this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find any question answer that would give me the desired behaviour that I am looking to achieve.

I have mostly the behaviour that I am looking to achieve, font style and colour, header height, etc. But, I can't seem to get the header to be transparent. I have been trying to do this by subclassing `NSTableHeaderCell` and override `- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame highlighted:(BOOL)isHighlighted inView:(NSView *)view;`

```
[[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.0 alpha:0.75] set];
NSRectFillUsingOperation(fillRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
```

The look I am trying to achieve is in this [screenshot](http://downloads.geektheory.ca/nstableheaderview-transparent.png). This being my first question ever, I had to host the image, because I don't have enough points to include an image in my question.

If someone could explain to me a little more how to achieve this style of header, or point me to the right documentation that would be grateful.

Comment: Did you finally found a way? I just have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

That is not a header view but rather a floating group row. Note position of the scrollbar: it's next to the "header" and not below.

Look for TableViewPlayground sample project, specifically "Complex Table View" example.
You can create a single floating group row in your table and make it look and act like a header view (i.e. show your own sort indicator and accept clicks to toggle sorting).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following works:

Objective-C:

```
[[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.0 alpha:0.75] set];
NSRectFill(fillRect);
```

Or in Swift:

```
NSColor(deviceWhite: 1.0, alpha: 0.65).setFill()
NSRectFill(fillRect)
```